# Automatically number a description list

Tags: numbering, lists, enumitem, description

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerated description list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list)

I would basically like to produce some kind of combination of an enumerate and a description environment. Manually

```
\begin{description}
\item[1. Item bla] \hfill \\
 Some text bla bla
\item[2. Item bla] \hfill \\
 Some more text bla bla
\end{description}
```

pretty much gives what I want. Each item should contain a counter together with a description (both equally formatted, e.g. bold) and some associated text starting on the next line.
So actually something like (sub)section heading plus text. But with separate counters and indentation etc.

Is there some nice package that will produce such formatting? Or would I need to somehow define a custom list structure?

Comment: Another solution can be found here:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list/30035#30035 In this case you don't need a special `item`.

Comment: This one has been marked as a duplicate of the newer question as the answer there is probably a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From an earlier question, try [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem/). In the example below, the `pifont` package is only needed for the first example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{212}]
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1,\\}}
\begin{enumerate}
\litem{Lo primero que ten\'{\i}a el Quijote} lanza en astillero,
\litem{Lo segundo} adarna antigua,
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Your second example is basically what I've been looking for.
However, I think for the second example the use of enumitem is not necessary, is it?

Comment: Good question. I just pulled that one from the enumitem manual, but if you get it to work with no extra packages, then it can be obviously be cut down. I haven't tried.