# enumitem package and description lists

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

Why does the following generate an error?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
 \begin{description}[label=\emph{\alph*})]
 \item [aaa] bbbb
 \item [eee] əəəə 
 \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add a brief description of your intent, we could suggest you a working alternative.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just want to number description list items via a neat method. I also saw other similar questions but the answer was not so clear and neat

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerated description list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Description lists don't admit a label in the sense of the `label` key of the `enumitem` package.

According to a comment to the original question, the purpose is to get description items numbered; in this case, you can use an `enumerate` environment (setting the `label` key appropriately to get the desired numbering) and a variant of `\item` to emulate the format of a description list; something along these lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries#1.\space}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*)}]
 \litem{Term one} First term description.
 \litem{Term two} Second term description.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

The `\item` of `description` lists must be formatted with `enumitem`'s `font` key (or its `format` synonym). Its last command can take an argument, so here's how to add a closing parenthesis after the item name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\textitplusparen}[1]{\textit{#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\textitplusparen]
\item [Item name] Some text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can even use `\item`, provided you do some juggling of the macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
  \let\latexitem\item
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{\latexitem\relax{\bfseries##1} }%
}
\newenvironment{descenum}[1][]
  {\begin{enumerate}[before=\changeitem,#1]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{descenum}
 \item[Term one] First term description.
 \item[Term two] Second term description.
\end{descenum}

\end{document}
```

The `descenum` environment accepts all kind of options good for `enumerate` (as provided by `enumitem`), for instance

```
\begin{descenum}[label=(\arabic*)]
 \item[Term one] First term description.
 \item[Term two] Second term description.
\end{descenum}
```