# Description environment with customized labels

Tags: description

Objective:

- Change font style, in this case removing bold;
- Customize the text into `Page <$my_text>.`; and
- Do this for a single description environment, I don't want to change the other ones.

To remove the bold I use `font=\normalfont` which seems to work. However, I cannot change the text format into `Page <$my_text>.`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!, labelwidth=0.3\textwidth, font=\normalfont, label=Page~*.]
  \item[12]       Hello.
  \item[33]       Text text text text text text text text.
  \item[92]       Some more text here.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you expect as label. Could you provide an example?

Comment: For instance `Page 12.` or `Page 33.` (without bold text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from [lockstep's answer on enumitem package and description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56252/3345):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\pageprefix}[1]{Page #1}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!, labelwidth=0.3\textwidth, font=\normalfont\pageprefix]
  \item[12]       Hello.
  \item[33]       Text text text text text text text text.
  \item[92]       Some more text here.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```