# Creating an enumerate-description style environment

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumerate, description

I've been trying to create a list environment to produce something that does the following:

1. It has a counter (like the enumerate environment).
2. The first line of each item is an overview of the item (probably in boldface).
3. Some items have nothing other than the first line, while others have more description.  The description is aligned with the title above it.

The following was my attempt:

```
\newcounter{numberdesc}
\newenvironment{numberdescription}{\begin{list}{}{%
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\textbf{\thenumberdesc.\hfill}}}}{%
  \end{list}}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{\stepcounter{numberdesc}\item\textbf{#1}\newline}

\begin{numberdescription}
\descitem{First item}
  has some description below it
\descitem{Second item does not}
\descitem{Third item}
  also has description
\end{numberdescription}
```

but I know that this is rather crude (not least the `\newline` in the definition of the `\item` replacement).

It was suggested to me in a previous attempt that the `enumitem` package does what I want, but as far as I can tell this doesn't align the text of the description in the manner I want.  To be specific: each item has a number and a title, and the text of the item should be aligned with the title but not the number.

I want it to produce something like the following (which was produced in a more crude manner):

[image]

Comment: have you seen [Enumerated description list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30029)

Comment: I've editted my original question to clarify that I want something that goes beyond (namely in terms of alignment) of the answers on that page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to avoid the newline if no content appears underneath?

Comment: Yes - I think that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to add `\par` after the heading.  You can build this in as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numberdesc}
\newenvironment{numberdescription}{\begin{list}{}{%
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\textbf{\thenumberdesc.\hfill}}}}{%
  \end{list}}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{\stepcounter{numberdesc}{\item\textbf{#1}\par}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text to show alignment.
\begin{numberdescription}
\descitem{First item}
  has some description below it
\descitem{Second item does not}
\descitem{Third item}
  also has description
\descitem{Fourth item}
  has some description below it
\descitem{Fifth item does not}
\descitem{Sixth item}
  also has description
\descitem{Seventh item}
  has some description below it
\descitem{Eight item does not}
\descitem{Ninth item is so long that it fills more than one line, but
that doesn't give us problems}
also has description
\descitem{Tenth item}
  has some description below it
\end{numberdescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  A very simple solution - I clearly need to remember the `\par` command.