# Change description environment indents

Tags: indentation, enumerate, description

I want to set (now wrong) `description` environment indents the same as (already correct) `enumerate` environment indents.

Note that I already use `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

How?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item a.
  \item b.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
  \item[1.] a.
  \item[2.] b.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The indents of two lists are different. I want to change `description` indent to become the same as `enumerate` indent.

**ADDENDUM**

I experimented with the below `amsbook` LaTeX file. In some reason, the indent of `enumerate` and `description` has not become the same as I desire. Please help me to find my error.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=1.7em,labelindent=*}
\setlist[description,1]{leftmargin=1.7em,labelindent=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item a.
  \item b.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
  \item[1.] a.
  \item[2.] b.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM 2**

By @Harish Kumar recommendation, I've also tried the following. The result is not ideal, `enumerate` and `description` do not have the same left margin.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
%   \hspace\labelsep \upshape #1.%
  \upshape #1.%
}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=2em,labelindent=*,label=\arabic*$^\circ$.,
ref=\arabic*$^\circ$} 
\setlist[description,1]{leftmargin=1em,labelindent=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{a} a.
  \item \label{b} b.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
  \item[\ref{a}] a.
  \item[\ref{b}] b.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen [Change hanging indent in `description` list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7008/5764)?

Comment: What kind of indentation are you after? What about the hanging indent?

Comment: @Werner: I've edited the question. I don't know whether hanging indent makes sense for me.

Comment: What's the point in using `description` when you want an enumerated list?

Comment: Related: [Creating an `enumerate`-`description` style environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100054/5764)

Comment: @egreg I want to create a list formatted like `enumerate` but with labels containing cross-references (sometimes not in ascending order) in the place of regular item labels. An example of what I want as a label: `(1)$\Rightarrow$(2)`. Or sometimes `description` items are easy like `\ref{xxx}.` should be formatted like as it if was an `enumerate` list.

Comment: @porton: You do know that you can use the optional argument of `\item` even inside an `enumerate` environment, don’t you?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I didn't know (or rather forgot) it. Well, I currently use LyX. In LyX it probably cannot be done :-(

Comment: @porton: I've just edited my answer: is it really _that_ what you want to do?  I don’t know about LyX, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request being made is not at all clear: if one just wants to typeset the labels of a `description` environment as if they were part of an `enumerate` environment, why should one use `description` at all?  Evidently, the question lacks some essential information.  A possible interpretation is that what is actually wanted here is to typeset a regular `description`-style label with a number sticking in the margin, with an alignment similar to that of the labels of `enumerate`.  The following example clarifies what I mean.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem} % actually redundant, in this example

\newenvironment*{descriptionThatMimicksItemize}{%
  \list{}{\let\makelabel\descriptionTMIlabel}%
}{\endlist}
\newcommand*{\descriptionTMIlabel}[1]{\hss\llap{\upshape #1}}
\makeatletter
  \@ifdefinable\origLabelWidth{\newdimen\origLabelWidth}
  \@ifdefinable\origLabelSep  {\newdimen\origLabelSep}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myNumericLabel}[1]{%
  \makebox[\origLabelWidth][r]{#1}\hspace{\origLabelSep}%
}

\begin{document}

\origLabelWidth = \labelwidth
\origLabelSep   = \labelsep
% This is an over-simplification, but for now we can accept it.

The \texttt{enumerate} environment:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{a}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
  \item \label{b}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
\end{enumerate}

The first solution:
\begin{descriptionThatMimicksItemize}
  \item[(\ref{a}) Is it this what you want?]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
  \item[(\ref{b}) I wouldn't say so.]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
\end{descriptionThatMimicksItemize}

The second one:
\begin{description}
  \item[\myNumericLabel{(\ref{a})}I'd rather say it's this]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
  \item[\myNumericLabel{(\ref{b})}A label is needed, though]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output produced]

If this is the real issue, it involves splitting the supplied label in two components, and therefore goes beyond the mere problem of setting the margins and the label width.

In conlusion, I think that it is impossible to fully answer this question until it is made clear what the precise request is.

**Addition**

I'm beginning to wonder whether it couldn’t be simply this what is actually wanted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook} % or whatever
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Let \( f\colon A\to B \) be a function.  The following are equivalent:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{a}  $f$ is both injective and surjective;
  \item\label{b}  $f$ is invertible.
\end{enumerate}
Proof:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[$\ref{a}\Rightarrow\ref{b}$:]
    Pick an element \( b\in B \), and let \( a\in A \) be the unique element 
    that is sent into~$b$ by~$f$\ldots
  \item[$\ref{b}\Rightarrow\ref{a}$:]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output of addede code]

Of course, the hyperlins work as expected.

But indeed, this wouldn’t be worth a bounty…

**Second Addition**

Yet another possibility:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook} % or whatever
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]
  {align=left, labelindent=.5em, labelwidth=1.5em}

\begin{document}

Let \( f\colon A\to B \) be a function.  The following are equivalent:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{a}  $f$ is both injective and surjective;
  \item\label{b}  $f$ is invertible.
\end{enumerate}
Proof:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[$\mbox{(\ref{a})}\Rightarrow\mbox{(\ref{b})}$:]
    Pick an element \( b\in B \), and let \( a\in A \) be the unique element 
    that is sent into~$b$ by~$f$\ldots
  \item[$\mbox{(\ref{a})}\Rightarrow\mbox{(\ref{b})}$:]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit iam 
    fugiaet enim duscula.  Reprivit ursula tum donec.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output #3:
[image: Output of third sample code]

Comment: I sometimes want a list which looks like enumerate, but differs in two things: 1. the items may be not in order (for example in order 2,3,1, not 1,2,3); 2. I prefer if the labels are hyperlinks. This can be done with description list with \ref commands. Otherwise this list should look exactly as an enumerate. Note that I use LyX and defining new list types may be a trouble for me, so I use existing list type "description".

Comment: I've compiled it. Now I see it is not what I want: The labels in the first enumerate and the second enumerate look differently, the indents are different. I need both list to look the same.

Comment: @porton: Added image for the output I get.  If you want the labels to be aligned on their left edge, instead, load the _enumitem_ package and specify `\begin{enumerate}[align=left]`.  It looks awful, anyway, IMHO.

Comment: No, it is not what I need. I probably cannot edit titles of items of enumerate with LyX. Maybe, I should switch to plain LaTeX to solve this problem :-(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to make any further trial, since I really cannot understand what you are looking for and what goes wrong with the code I’ve posted.

Comment: I am looking for changing description environment to look the same as enumerate environment (provided that the labels are the same). Your code is not what I need because I probably cannot add custom labels to enumerate items, because this is probably unsupported in LyX.

Comment: `\let\description=\enumerate`.

Comment: Did I really write “trial” instead of “try”?  Yet I see it before my eyes.  Very embarassing; but I’m not going to delete the comment and repost it (editing it is impossible), lest the order of replies be subverted.

Comment: \let\description=\enumerate does exactly what I requested. However when I looked actual formatting of my book, I realized that what I requested is not what I need. Because you answered my question, I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item a.
  \item b.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=1.7em,labelindent=*,before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1}}]
  \item[1.] a.
  \item[2.] b.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is probably specific for `article` document class. But I want it to work for `amsbook` and if possible for every document class. Can you help?

Comment: @porton What makes you think that this will not work for amsbook or any other class? I say try it. This answer is meant to show you how to do it.  You can always adjust `leftmargin`, `labelindent` and `before` code to suit your needs.

Comment: I've edited the question. It does not work as expected. Please help.

Comment: @porton: You can adjust: `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=2em,labelindent=*}
\setlist[description,1]{leftmargin=1em,labelindent=*}`.

Comment: The result is not good. See "addendum 2" in my question.