# Customized bold labels for enumerate

Tags: enumerate, labels, bold, enumitem

I would like to have bold enumerate labels that both have a Roman numeral and a custom text in them, like on page 26 (pdf page 2) of http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/stml-48-prev.pdf.

I'm using the following code to just have bold Roman numerals (using enumitem), but I can't figure out how to add custom text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Roman*}]
    \item item one.
    \item item two.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30029/3929

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of achieving this "manually" would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[\bfseries I.]
    \item \textbf{Some text:} item one.
    \item \textbf{Some other text:} item two.
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

Which would look like this:

[image]

If you want the same kind of coustom text for all items you could use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[\bfseries I. {Same text for all items}:]
    \item item one.
    \item item two.
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Which would look like this:

[image]