# Filling blank alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I want write a test with several question of filling blank questions. But I don't like the result. Because some sentences are shown in two or more lines, and a piece of the text is below the line for to be filled. I want that all the text below of the line was align with the first letter after the blank in the first line of the sentence.
I'm using a enumerate environment like:

```
 \begin{enumerate}
      \item \underline{\hspace{2.5cm}} \hspace{1em} bla bla bla bla ....
\end{enumerate}
```

And I want, how I said before, the text was aligned to the first "b".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you mean. Could you provide an image that shows what you want? And perhaps we should be clear about the code by means of a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 2):

Or using TeX prmitives:

[image]

```
\def\fbindent{3cm}
\def\dorule{\leaders\vrule depth2pt height-1.6pt \hfil}
\def\fb#1.{\noindent\hbox to\fbindent{\bf#1. \dorule\ }%
  \hangindent=\fbindent \ignorespaces}

\fb 1. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.

\fb 2. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.

\fb 3. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.
```

Answer (score 1):

Marco Daniel's solution to [Enumerated description list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list) may help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{descriptcount}
\renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=3.2cm, style=sameline,
before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}},
font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount .]
\item [\underline{\hspace{2.5cm}}]
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item [\underline{\hspace{2.5cm}}]
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item [\underline{\hspace{2.5cm}}]
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that sets every `\question` inside a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), making it unbreakable across the page boundary *within* a question. The optional argument allows you to specify the number, otherwise it naturally increments with every use of `\question`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,xparse}

\newcounter{question}
\newlength{\questionlen}
\setlength{\questionlen}{7em}
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{o m}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}p{\questionlen} X@{}}
    \bfseries
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% \question{..}
      \stepcounter{question}%
      \thequestion. \hrulefill
    }{% \question[.]{..}
      #1 \hrulefill
    }%
    & #2
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}

\question{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.}

\question{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.}

\question[4.]{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.}

\setlength{\questionlen}{10em}

\question{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla.}

\end{document}
```

Adjustment of the question width is done using `\setlength{\questionlen}{<width>}`.