# Adding some common text to enumerated description lists

Tags: enumitem, description

This question is actually based on a modified version of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30035/14103). The original solution works perfectly well.

However, I wanted to add the word **Case** before the number and a comma after the number. While the word before the number works, a comma after the number throws an error which I have failed to solve.

Here is the modified source:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{1}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}},
        font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}Case \thedescriptcount,~
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumdescript}
   \item item one
   \item item two
   \item[Some Text] item three
   \item item four
   \item item five
\end{enumdescript}
\end{document}
```

This generates an error,

> ```
> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \protect 
> l.15    \item
>               item one
> ?
> ```

If the comma after `\thedescriptcount` is removed, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Try `font={....,~}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  setting `font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}Case \thedescriptcount,` will lead to the typesetting as requested, but the `,` should be a part of the typesetting, not being handled as separator of the key-value interface. Omitting a `{}` pair around this leads to a `~` as a key, which is not understood by `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{1}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}},
        font={\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}Case \thedescriptcount,~}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumdescript}
   \item item one
   \item item two
   \item[Some Text] item three
   \item item four
   \item item five
\end{enumdescript}
\end{document}
```

[image]