# table like entry without the table bars in overleaf latex

Tags: tables, alignment

I am new to latex overleaf and  I want to have something like the following

```
topic       Main topic and content of the paper

relevance   Explanation of why and how the paper is relevant to
            the topic
role        Role which the publication will play in the seminar
            work
```

An example would be this

[image]

Any help is appreciated, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better what your problem is ...

Comment: The simplest would be using a custom `description` environment (which is easily done with `enumitem`).

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the suggestion. I looked at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list but I don't want a numbering of the items. Did you mean this?

Comment: @Gunners: no, I didn't. A description environment is not an enumerate environment. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the `description` environment (which is not numbered) with the help of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries relevance}, leftmargin=!]
  \item[topic] \lipsum[11]
  \item[relevance] \lipsum[12]
  \item[role]\lipsum[13]

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]