# Remove indentation

Tags: spacing, indentation, sections-paragraphs, vertical-spacing

How can I remove indentation between enumeration and text? I tried `\noindent` but it didn't work.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=0.7cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \def\Date{22/03/22}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
        \item   \textbf{Introduction}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
        \color{gray}
        
        \item   Purpose
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \color{black}
     This procedure describes the risk management method that must be applied: 
        Within the framework of the processes control,
        Within the framework of the process of product realization.
    
    The Quality System Risk management is a systematic process for identification, assessment, control, communication and review of risks to the quality system processes. It is just acknowledging that risk happens, and taking measures to ensure we are completely prepared for it.
    
      \vspace{0.5cm}
    \color{gray}
     \item  Field of application
     
    \color{black}
      \vspace{0.5cm}
    This procedure applies to all process and product risk analyses conducted within DiappyMed. 
    
      \vspace{0.5cm}
    \color{gray}
     \item  Definitions
       \vspace{0.5cm}
       
    \color{black}
    \textbf{Risk Analysis}
    Use of available information to identify hazardous phenomena and estimate the risk
    
    \textbf{Damage}
    Physical injury or damage to the health of persons, or damage to property or the environment
    
    \textbf{Severity}
    Measure of the possible consequences of a dangerous phenomenon
    
    
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the left-hand indentation from the firstl-level list, the second-level list, or both? Please advise.

Comment: actually i want to remove both and also the space between list and text

Comment: Thanks. Please also clarify what you mean by "space between list and text".

Comment: sorry if i didn't clarify but i want to the paragraph text starts on the extreme  left on the same level as the number of enumeration .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of the modified `description` list as suggested [@Marco Daniel answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30029/enumerated-description-list) in your case  enable to write a bit shorter and simpler code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{descriptcount}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\Alph*,wide]
\item\textbf{Introduction}
    \begin{description}[before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}},%
                        font=\color{gray}\normalfont%
                             \stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount.~,
                        topsep=5mm,itemsep=3mm,parsep=3mm,
                        wide
                             ]
        \item[Purpose]~

        This procedure describes the risk management method that must be applied:
        Within the framework of the processes control,
        Within the framework of the process of product realization.

        The Quality System Risk management is a systematic process for
        identification, assessment, control, communication and review of
        risks to the quality system processes. It is just acknowledging
        that risk happens, and taking measures to ensure we are completely
        prepared for it.

        \item[Field of application]~

        This procedure applies to all process and product risk analyses
        conducted within DiappyMed.

        \item[Definitions]~

        \textbf{Risk Analysis}
        Use of available information to identify hazardous phenomena
        and estimate the risk

        \textbf{Damage}
        Physical injury or damage to the health of persons, or damage
        to property or the environment

        \textbf{Severity}
        Measure of the possible consequences of a dangerous phenomenon
    \end{description}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? (If the outcome of `wide=0pt` is too extreme for your taste, give `left=0pt` a try.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.27cm,top=0.7cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\Alph*,wide=0pt]
\item\textbf{Introduction}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\color{gray}\arabic*.,
                      topsep=5mm,itemsep=5mm,
                      wide=0pt]
    
    \item \textcolor{gray}{Purpose}
    \par\vspace{3mm}
    
    This procedure describes the risk management method that must be applied: 
    Within the framework of the processes control,
    Within the framework of the process of product realization.

    The Quality System Risk management is a systematic process for
    identification, assessment, control, communication and review of 
    risks to the quality system processes. It is just acknowledging 
    that risk happens, and taking measures to ensure we are completely
    prepared for it.

    \item \textcolor{gray}{Field of application}
    \par\vspace{3mm}
    
    This procedure applies to all process and product risk analyses 
    conducted within DiappyMed. 

    \item \textcolor{gray}{Definitions}
    \par\vspace{3mm}
    
    \textbf{Risk Analysis}
    Use of available information to identify hazardous phenomena 
    and estimate the risk

    \textbf{Damage}
    Physical injury or damage to the health of persons, or damage 
    to property or the environment

    \textbf{Severity}
    Measure of the possible consequences of a dangerous phenomenon

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```