# The format of references to enumitem's enumeration lists items

Tags: enumitem

I have a list of axioms, and I am using `enumitem` to label them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\fmt[1]{$\mathbf{(#1)}$}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[format=\fmt]

\item[Ex_1]\label{ax1} The sky is blue.

\item[Egreg_\infty]\label{ax2} Another item.

\end{enumerate}
The first condition is \ref{ax1}
\end{document}
```

All the `\item`s have their optional parameter, because the names do not follow a simple pattern. I'd like the `\ref` to be formatted in exactly the same way as the label appears in the list. But it seems that when `\item` is given its optional argument it does not even emit a anchor for a reference, let alone format the reference like the label.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's pretty normal, I'd say. Can you expand the example code so that the different patterns can be seen?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as: [enumitem - labels fine - but references defined empty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80526)

Comment: @egreg, well, that's easy: just copy the `\item` I wrote and replace `Ex_1` by `Unit` :-) The items are axioms for things, and their names are short appreviations (sometimes with decorations, like `Ex_3'`)

Comment: @AlanMunn, modulo the fact that egreg's solution there has the `\ref`s be the counter values, not the actual labels.

Answer (score 3):

Use a different mark up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareRobustCommand\fmt[1]{$\mathbf{(#1)}$}
\newenvironment{axioms}
 {\enumerate[format=\fmt]}
 {\endenumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\axiom}[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\fmt{#1}}\item[#1]%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{axioms}

\axiom{Ex_1}\label{ax1} The sky is blue.

\axiom{Egreg_\infty}\label{ax2} Another item.

\end{axioms}

The first condition is \ref{ax1}, while the second is \ref{ax2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One can probably redefine `\item` in the `before` of list to avoid using a different markup, I guess.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sure, but why? Good markup is rewarding in the long run.